# In which books does Descartes propose his ideas about mind-body dualism?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, descartes, mind-body

In which books does Descartes propose his ideas about mind-body dualism?

Answer (score 1):

You can start with [Dualism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dualism/), [René Descartes](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes/) and [Descartes and the Pineal Gland](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/).

Then you can see at least :

- Desmond M. Clarke, [Descartes's Theory of Mind](https://books.google.it/books?id=vdMuz_75vRYC&printsec=frontcover) (2005)
- Lilli Alanen, [Descartes's Concept of Mind](https://books.google.it/books?id=c0Z7LQuFtTYC&printsec=frontcover) (2009)
- Dennis Des Chene, [Spirits and Clocks: Machine and Organism in Descartes](https://books.google.it/books?id=hSbaGnX9S5UC&printsec=frontcover) (2001).

About D's works, you can see his first book, the [Treatise of man](https://books.google.it/books?id=YWpErQ3g_pEC&printsec=frontcover) (written before 1637, but only published posthumously, first in an imperfect Latin translation in 1662, and then in the original French in 1664).